# Assignment changing outside control structure

Tags: elixir

I'm starting with Elixir and having a hard time understanding why assignments change when outside of a control structure. Clarifying, this is what I mean (`.exs` file):

```
defmodule Grocery do
  def add(map, item, count) do
    Map.put(map, item, count)
  end

  def remove(map, item, count) do
    new_map = %{map | item => map[item] - count}

    if new_map[item] <= 0 do 
      new_map = Map.delete(new_map, item)
      IO.inspect new_map, label: :inside_if
    end

    IO.inspect new_map, label: :outside_if
  end
end

map = %{whey: 2, bread: 1}

map = Grocery.add(map, :egg, 30)
#IO.inspect map

map = Grocery.remove(map, :bread, 1)
#IO.inspect map
```

The inspect results are:

```
inside_if: %{egg: 30, whey: 2}
outside_if: %{bread: 0, egg: 30, whey: 2}
```

I appreciate it if someone could explain what's happening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: this is a scoping issue. Each control statement in Elixir declares a new scope. To make it work as expected, assign the value on the top level:

```rb
new_map = 
  if new_map[item] <= 0,
  do: Map.delete(new_map, item),
  else: new_map
```

---

Detailed explanation. `if` in Elixir is a macro. Macros have [hygiene](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html#macro-hygiene) to prevent the calling code from unwanted modifications by injected AST. That is why whatever was declared inside `if` stays inside `if`.

The outer scope has its own environment and hence its own set of variables. The outer scope variable cannot be modified from the inner scope. These are basically two different variables, sharing the name (and since the inner scope is a closure, it has all the outer scope variables copied, that’s why one can access the value of the `new_map` from inside `if` in your example.)